# Calcular monto total de hipoteca en Python

Tags: python

Intento con distintos parámetros calcular el monto de un ejercicio sobre una hipoteca, pero a veces no me aparece en la terminal el resultado que quiero a no ser que elimine una variable. El problema es que es indispensable el desarrollo.

El enunciado es este:

Marcos solicitó un crédito a 30 años para comprar una casa, con una tasa fija nominal anual del 5%. Pidió $500000 al banco y acordó un pago mensual fijo de $2684,11. Pero ahora Marcos adelanta pagos extra de $1000/mes durante los primeros 12 meses de la hipoteca.

Ahora debes modificar el programa para incorporar estos pagos extra y que imprima el monto total pagado junto con la cantidad de meses requeridos.

Cuando lo corras, este nuevo programa debería dar un pago total de 929965.62 en 348 meses.

El codigo de base seria este:

```
saldo = 500000.0
tasa = 0.05
pago_mensual = 2684.11
pago_extra = 1000
total_pagado = 0.0
mes = 0.0

while saldo > 0:
    saldo = saldo * (1+tasa/12) - pago_mensual - mes - pago_extra
    total_pagado = total_pagado + pago_mensual + mes + pago_extra
    mes = mes + 1

print('Total pagado', total_pagado)
```

La variable indispensable es el `mes`, intente inicializarlo en 0 para que salga del ciclo contando la cantidad de pagos que se hicieron pero no funciono.

Seria un golazo si me pudiesen orientar en como organizarlo.

Comment: ¿El código publicado es parte del enunciando?

Comment: Si, es parte del enunciado.

Comment: Si el código es el que viene en el enunciado que has intentado?

Comment: Exacto. El codigo en si es el mismo solo sin la variable ```mes``` agregada en el ciclo y la primera declaracion. El problema es que estoy fallando en como inicializarla u organizarla de forma adecuada.

Comment: `pago_mensual` son pesos/dolares;  `mes` es un escalar. No tiene sentido sumarlos.

Comment: Oka estaba fallando en eso entonces. Ahora me fijo que otros operadores puedo usar

Comment: El otro problema con el ejercicio es que el pago mensual fijo es demasiado bajo; la deuda crecerá eternamente.

Comment: Si la idea es que como se paga en 30 años va a tomar 348 meses en pagarlo te de finalmente el monto de ```929965.62``` al final de ese periodo. Me olvide de agregar eso en el enunciado. Que no puedo obtener ese monto

Comment: Entonces `saldo` siempre será positivo y el `while saldo > 0:` no terminara nunca.

Comment: El `929965.62` me sale, un ´while`,  pero los meses me dan 342. Probé mi código con un calculador de hipotecas y me salía. Si obtienes la solución no dejes de ponerla para ver el error

Answer (score 1):

```
mes=0
mes_extra=12
mensualidad=2684.11
extra=1000
hipoteca=500000
saldado=0
anio=0
while hipoteca>0:
  hipoteca+=hipoteca*5/100
  porcentaje_negativo=1000*0.05
  anio+=1
  print('\n----año 
  {}\nhipoteca-> ${}\nMonto 
  saldado ->${}'.format(anio,round(hipoteca,2),round(saldado,2)))
  print('porcentaje anual--> {}'.format(round(hipoteca*5/100,2)))
  for i in range(1,13):
    hipoteca=hipoteca- 
    mensualidad-extra
    mes+=1
    saldado+=mensualidad
    if mes_extra<=0:
      extra=0
    mes_extra-=1
print('\n___________\nmeses--> {}\nmonto total--> ${}'.format(mes,round(saldado,2)))
```

Comment: Hola buenas he creado este código y he puesto refernecias de cada año para ir viendo la evolucion de la hipoteca, al final me salen los 348 mesas pero el monto total supera por un poco de la salida esperada, creo que esos $1000 que se pagan durante esos mese com extra deberían de llevar un 5% a parte de la anual o alguna peñalizacion  de algún tipo de interes.

Answer (score 0):

```
saldo = 500000.0
tasa = 0.05
pago_mensual = 2684.11
total_pagado = 0.0
mes=1

pago_extra_mes_comienzo = 61
pago_extra_mes_fin = 108
pago_extra = 1000



while (saldo >= pago_mensual):

    
   if (mes >= pago_extra_mes_comienzo) and (mes <= pago_extra_mes_fin):
    saldo = saldo * (1+tasa/12) - (pago_mensual+pago_extra)
    total_pagado = total_pagado + (pago_mensual+pago_extra)
   else:
   

    saldo = saldo * (1+tasa/12) - pago_mensual
    total_pagado = total_pagado + pago_mensual

   print("mes numero:", mes, "total pagado hasta el momento:", round(total_pagado,2),'Saldo restante:', round(saldo, 2))

   mes = mes + 1  


while saldo< pago_mensual:
   print("último mes:", mes,"total pagado hasta el momento:", round((saldo + total_pagado),2)," Nunca vuelvas a hipotecarte!!!" )
       
   saldo=0
   pago_mensual=0
```

Comment: no creo que sea el código más elegante... pero funciona

Comment: Solo creo que le falto algo de contexto a la respuesta, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)